# Local volume includes invalid characters

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-machine

I am trying to mount local directory to docker container. Here is the command that i use:

```
docker run -itd --rm --name chatbot --mount source="$(pwd)",target=/instagram-dm-webhook-service  chatbot:12
```

Where current working dir is: `/home/user/instagram-dm-webhook-service`

I get this error:

> "/home/user/instagram-dm-webhook-service" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.

So if i understand this, having dash character in path is ok. Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 4):

**Interestingly adding only this didn't work either**, `/` here `"/$(pwd)"`

- **volume**: *mounts a managed volume into the container*.
- **bind**: *bind-mounts a directory or file from the host into the container*.

for more details on mount types - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#add-bind-mounts-or-volumes

So you **need to explicitly add** the `mount` **type to** `bind` **for mounting a directory.**

```
docker run -it --mount type=bind,source="/$(pwd)",target=/root ubuntu:18.04 /bin/bash
root@eda980649055:/# cd /root
root@eda980649055:~# ls
Jenkinsfile.migrate  LICENSE.txt  README.md  pom.xml  src  target
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a / before $(pwd)

```
docker run -itd --rm --name chatbot --mount source="/$(pwd)",target=/instagram-dm-webhook-service  chatbot:12
```

Comment: affirmative, it has to be an absolute path